# How to set height of Gallery view cell equals Gallery height?

Tags: android

I have Gallery control with ImageView as cell View. I need to have ImageView size equals the Gallery height. How can I do that? I tried to set height like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        FrameLayout retval = (FrameLayout) convertView;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(parent.getHeight(), parent.getHeight()));
```

But first cell has height equals zero but next cells has right value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the imageView to fill the parent container through the params?

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        FrameLayout retval = (FrameLayout) convertView;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) retval.findViewById(R.id.image);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

That is, unless you want the width of the imageview to be equal to the height of the gallery. Then this would not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set layoutParams on cell itself and let image view to scaleXY to the cell.

```
retval.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(parent.getHeight(), parent.getHeight());
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```